# css black text contains colorized pixel

Tags: html, css, printing, colors

**If you closely inspect black text on a html page (using Firefox Developer Tool - Eyedropper for example), you can detect colorized pixels around the text. 
Does anybody know how to alter this so that the text becomes full black or grayscale?**

A short narrative why I'm asking this;

I'm creating a pdf from a html page using the open source command line tool 'wkhtmltopdf'. I'm trying to create a full grayscale html page so that when I set my printers' color settings to auto, it would create a grayscale print instead of a color print. At the moment, this isn't the case and I suspect this is because there a colorized pixels in my document.

extra info: 
I can't simply put my printers color settings to grayscale because I should have a mixed pdf with grayscale pages and color pages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think you can do this by adding the following to your `CSS`:

```
.yourelementwithfonts
{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: Will your printer detect a real grayscale document and changes his settings automaticly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's something to do with text anti-aliasing 
Chrome is really good with this stuff.
It's not a standard feature and not supported by a lot of browsers.

The code dat kobby provided will do your job

You  can still take a look here

[CSS documentation for mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth)